Minority carrier concentration on the depletion zone boundary during forward bias. Where does restriction to $x_p$ comes from?
Question.
I have a question about the pn-junction under forward bias. I am interested in minority carrier concentration on the depletion zone boundary. The expression for it is: $n_p(x_p)=n_{p0} exp(q\frac{V}{kT})$. Why doesn't hold outside the boundary? I sort of understand the derivation, but I don't understand where the restriction to $x_p$ comes from.
My attempt.
So I know that there are several approaches in deriving minority carrier concentrations at the pn-junction depletion zone boundaries. One of them exploits quasi-equilibrium condition.
As far I understand Fermi level for the holes is defined as $n=N_c exp(\frac{E_{Fn}-E_c}{kT})$ and
$p=N_v exp(\frac{E_v-E_{Fp}}{kT})$. So They can be multiplied together to obtain $np=n_i^2 exp(q\frac{E_{Fn}-E_{Fp}}{kT})=n_i^2 exp(q\frac{V}{kT})$.
Now let us consider $x_p$ boundary, that is depletion region boundary in p-type semiconductor. So we can rewrite the pn-junction law as:
$n_p p_p=n_i^2 exp(q\frac{V}{kT})$. We know that $p_p=N_A$, because when current flows trough diode concentrations of majority carriers stay almost unchanged. So we get:
$n_p N_A=n_i^2 exp(q\frac{V}{kT})$, using $n_{p0} N_A=n_i^2$ we obtain:
$n_p=n_{p0} exp(q\frac{V}{kT})$. This equation holds only for minority carriers in p-region on the depletion region boundary. So I am questioning where this restriction comes from? I am interested in logically deriving it. So I am more interested in mathematical part of it.
P.S. I am a chemist. Many obvious things to you are far from obvious to me. This I because I usually operate with different things than you do. So lets stick to predicate logic. I have red a few books on it.
Update.

So here we can see that $n=N_c exp(\frac{E_{Fn}-E_c}{kT})$ apply in $x \in (-\infty,x_p]$. Also we can see that $p=N_v exp(\frac{E_v-E_{Fp}}{kT})$ apply for $x \in [x_N,+\infty)$. So we conclude that their product expression is valid only for region $x \in [x_N,x_p]$.
So if I understand correctly n_p(x_p)=n(x= any value from x_N to x_p).
So new question arise: why expressions for relations between quasi-Fermi level energies and carrier concentration are valid in depletion zone?

I am not sure what it is you are confused about. Only on the $p$ side of the $pn$-junction will you have $p_p\approx N_A$, and that automatically sets a limit. The dependency is an exponential, and it either quickly explodes way bigger than is tolerably called "minority", or it quickly diminishes to nearly zero. In another way to see the physics, the charge transferred region is going to be some small region, and the formula you obtained is only applicable within that region.

Do I understand correctely. There are formulas for quasi-equalibrium carrier concentration. But these both formulas work simultaniusely only in deplition region. So these formulas mostly apply for major carriers, but they work for minority carriers on deplition zone boundaries too.
